# Returning modified Observable value Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Consider the following example:

```
 login(context: LoginContext): Observable<Credentials> {

    let credentials = JSON.stringify(context);

    this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:64636/api/Account/login", credentials, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      })
    }).subscribe(response => {
      let token = (<any>response).token;

      const data = {
        username: context.username,
        token: token
      };

      this.setCredentials(data, context.remember);
      return of(data);

    }, err => {

    });


  }
```

Here what I am trying to achieve is to encapsulate the data that is received from the `httpClient` and return it, but this is done after the execution of httpClient is complete. The compiler tells me that "a function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value" and rightfully so. My question is, how to resolve such issue when the parent observable must wait for the httpClient.post() observable to finish its task?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `return` before the `this.httpClient.post...` and subscribing to `login` ?

Comment: Yes that would work but the thing is, I want to do the work of encapsulating this received data within the login function and then return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [map operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) to modify the value returned by an Observable:

```
login(context: LoginContext): Observable<Credentials> {

  let credentials = JSON.stringify(context);

  return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:64636/api/Account/login", credentials, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })
  }).pipe(
    map(response => {
      let token = (<any>response).token;
      const data = {
        username: context.username,
        token: token
      };
      this.setCredentials(data, context.remember);
      return data;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeap, I was just reading the map operator description myself. This is the correct way to achieve my goal. Thank you.

Comment: However, this does not get rid of the error "a function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value "

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to `return` the Observable. I made the correction. I assume that `data` is compatible with the `Credentials` class type (you may have to cast the value).